# Need to Convert Object Id column in a dataframe to date

Tags: python, mongodb, time, objectid

[image]

This is a pandas dataframe. I want to convert '_id_x' column to timestamp/date. I have tried with "*testSummary['time'] = (testSummary[ObjectId('_id_x')]).generation_time*". But getting error : '_id_x' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string.
How to solve this?

Comment: Hello there. Try something like `testSummary['time'] = testSummary['_id_x'].generation_time`

Comment: @AristotelisPozidis Tried "testSummary['time'] = testSummary['_id_x'].generation_time". But getting error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'generation_time'

Comment: Hmm yes thats right. Because df column is a Series. So you need to do something like that: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html). I edit this comment to add what i think will solve your issue: testSummary['time'] = testSummary['_id_x'].dt.generation_time

Comment: if the _id_x column comes from the mongo autogenerated id, you can't do it that way, because it has a timestamp, a random value and an incrementing value on it. You should get it from the query to mongo using **ObjectId.getTimestamp()**, so you will retrive in one column the timestamp part of the Id as a date. You can read about it _https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/_

Answer (score -1):

So based on my previous comment. I add an answer here.

Hope it will help. Check it from [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)

How to make a dt.accessor. [link2](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
...
df['_id_x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_id_x'], errors='coerce')
df['time'] = df['_id_x'].dt.datetime
```

Comment: Cannot get correct solution with this. Getting error: "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: I updated my answer with (How to make an accessor of dt)